# TypeError on Angular form submit

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting the error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'songname' of null`, when trying to submit an update to a row in firebase. The console error is saying that its happening with the `record.songname` in the edit function. I'm able to add, but not edit rows.

```
myApp.controller('ProductsCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $http){

  var myProducts = new Firebase('https://url-to-db.firebaseio.com/songs');

  $scope.products = $firebaseArray(myProducts);

  $scope.showForm = function(){
    $scope.addFormShow = true;
    $scope.editFormShow = false;
    clearForm();
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  $scope.hideForm = function(){
    $scope.addFormShow = false;
  }

  function clearForm(){
    $scope.songname = '';
    $scope.artist = '';
    $scopt.tags = '';
  }

  $scope.addFormSubmit = function(){
    $scope.products.$add({
      songname:$scope.songname,
      artist:$scope.artist,
      tags:$scope.tags,
      date:Date.now()
    });
    $('.messages').addClass('alert alert-success').slideDown().show().html('The song has been added').fadeOut(2000);
    clearForm();
  }

  $scope.dateFormat = 'MM-dd-yy @ HH:mm:ss';

  $scope.showProduct = function(product){
    $scope.editFormShow = true;
    $scope.addFormShow = false;
    $scope.songname = product.songname;
    $scope.artist = product.artist;
    $scope.tags = product.tags;
    $scope.date = product.date;
  }

  $scope.editFormSubmit = function(){
    var id = $scope.id;
    var record = $scope.products.$getRecord(id);
    record.songname = $scope.songname;
    record.artist = $scope.artist;
    record.tags = $scope.tags;

    $scope.products.$save(record);
    $('.messages').addClass('alert alert-info').slideDown().show().html('The job has been edited').fadeOut(2000);
    clearForm();
    $('.edit-form').toggle();
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $scope.id attribute is probably not getting set.
Try setting the id in the scope in your showProduct function or whichever function initializes the $scope variables for the item.

```
$scope.showProduct = function(product){
$scope.id = product.id;
..............
```

Comment: I already have the id set in the function that submits the edits, which is where the error is showing, by using `var id = $scope.id;` which is passed to getRecord().

Comment: What I meant was that the value in the $scope.id attribute itself was not being set anywhere. So, when you say `var id = $scope.id`, all it is effectively doing is `var id = undefined`